# Getting an error here, not sure what it is though

Tags: c++, visual-c++, file-io, inputstream, outputstream

my build is totally successful here, yet not outputting to my text file, I know I asked a question a few days ago about this program, and I've since changed it. What am I doing wrong now?

Thanks in advance guys.
I'm trying to input from an employeesIn.txt file and create an employeesOut.txt file made of employee structures.

Here's my text file.

```
123,John,Brown,125 Prarie Street,Staunton,IL,62088
124,Matt,Larson,126 Hudson Road,Edwardsville,IL,62025
125,Joe,Baratta,1542 Elizabeth Road,Highland,IL,62088
126,Kristin,Killebrew,123 Prewitt Drive,Alton,IL,62026
127,Tyrone,Meyer,street,999 Orchard Lane,Livingston,62088
```

The output should look like

Employee Record: 123
Name: John Brown
Home Address: 125 Prarie Street 
Staunton, IL 62088

Employee Record: 124
Name Matt Larson
Home Address:.... and so on

Here's my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

struct Person {
    string first;
    string last;
};

struct Address {
    string street;
    string city;
    string state;
    string zipcode;
};

struct Employee {
    Person name;
    Address homeAddress;
    int eid;
};

int readEmployee(istream& in, Employee eArray[]);
void displayEmployee(ostream& out,Employee eArray[], int EmployeePopulation);
const int arr=50;
Employee eArray[arr];

ifstream fin;
ofstream fout;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{   
    fin.open("employeesIn.txt");

    if (!fin.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Error opening employeesIn.txt for reading." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    fout.open("employeesOut.txt");
    if (!fout.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Error opening employeesOut.txt for writing." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    int tingle = readEmployee(fin, eArray);

    fin.close();
    displayEmployee(fout, eArray, tingle);        
    fout.close();

    exit(0);
}

int readEmployee(istream& in, Employee eArray[])
{
    string eidText;
    string line;
    getline(in, line);

    int EmployeePopulation = 0;
    while (!in.eof()) {    
        getline(in, eidText, ',');
        eArray[EmployeePopulation].eid = stoi(eidText);
        getline(in, eArray[EmployeePopulation].name.first, ',');
        getline(in, eArray[EmployeePopulation].name.last, ',');
        getline(in, eArray[EmployeePopulation].homeAddress.street, ',');
        getline(in, eArray[EmployeePopulation].homeAddress.city, ',');
        getline(in, eArray[EmployeePopulation].homeAddress.state, ',');
        getline(in, eArray[EmployeePopulation].homeAddress.zipcode);
        EmployeePopulation++;        
    }
    return EmployeePopulation;    
}

void displayEmployee(ostream& out, Employee eArray[], int EmployeePopulation)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= EmployeePopulation - 1; i++) {
        out << "Employee Record: " << eArray[i].eid
            << endl
            << "Name: " << eArray[i].name.first << " " << eArray[i].name.last
            << endl
            << "Home address: " << eArray[i].homeAddress.street
            << endl
            << eArray[i].homeAddress.city << ", " << eArray[i].homeAddress.state << " " <<  eArray[i].homeAddress.zipcode
            << endl
            << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: I'm not getting an error, it's just not outputting to the file as I thought it would.

Comment: Your title is quite misleading then.  Have you stepped through the program in the debugger?  Are you sure anything is being read?  `while (!fin.eof())` is almost always wrong, you should check the return value from that actual reads, not hope to catch a problem after it has occurred.

Comment: The last line in your text file `127,Tyrone,Meyer,street,999 Orchard Lane,Livingston,62088` doesn't match the format of the others.

Comment: What is the expected output?  What is the actual output?

Comment: I changed my text file, and updated my original code in the post above. But still no change to the output. I will put what the output should look like in the employeesOut.txt file in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

You should use `return 0` rather than `exit(0)` at the end of main.

Checking for `eof` after you have performed several reads and tried to convert the data is wrong.  You need to check for failure of the reads themselves.

This corrects the `eof` issue.  The program was crashing for me because `stoi` threw an exception when the read failed.

```
int readEmployee(istream& in, Employee eArray[])
{
    string eidText;
    string line;
    //This discards the first line.  Incorrect for the test data you supplied.
    getline(in, line);

    int EmployeePopulation = 0;
    //Check for errors while reading, not eof after the fact.
    //This was crashing because stoi failed when no data was
    //read due to eof being true after the loop check.
    while(  getline(in, eidText, ',') &&
            getline(in, eArray[EmployeePopulation].name.first, ',') &&
            getline(in, eArray[EmployeePopulation].name.last, ',') &&
            getline(in, eArray[EmployeePopulation].homeAddress.street, ',') &&
            getline(in, eArray[EmployeePopulation].homeAddress.city, ',') && 
            getline(in, eArray[EmployeePopulation].homeAddress.state, ',') &&
            getline(in, eArray[EmployeePopulation].homeAddress.zipcode))
    {
        eArray[EmployeePopulation].eid = stoi(eidText);
        EmployeePopulation++;
    }
    return EmployeePopulation;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have fewer problems if you used a `vector` of `Employee`.
You could pass it by reference to the functions.
The functions could get the number of employees by using `std::vector::size()`.
The `std::vector` automatically expands when using the `push_back` method.

If you created input and output methods for your classes, you wouldn't have to violate encapsulation:

```
class Person // using class to support privacy and encapsulation
{
    std::string first_name;
    std::string last_name;
  public:
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inp, Person& p);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Person& p);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inp, Person& p)
{
  std::getline(inp, p.first_name, ',');
  std::getline(inp, p.last_name, ',');
}

std:ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Peron& p)
{
  out << "Name: ";
  out << p.first_name;
  out << " ";
  out << p.last_name;
}

class Employee
{
  Person name;
  Address addr;
  public:
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inp, Employee& e);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inp, Employee& e)
{
  inp >> name;
  inp >> addr;
};
```

The missing formatted input and output are left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

In your `readEmployee` function, you passed `isstream& in`.I suppose you should be checking for `while (!in.eof())` ans not `while (!fin.eof())`. 
And your `getline(fin, line);` should be `getline(in, line);` too.

Comment: Have made these updates to the code above, output is still nothing :/